# flatiron.js / union - where to put app.use() configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatiron.js, nodejitsu

Taking the [simple example](https://github.com/flatiron/union/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.js) from Union, I am wondering where I can put configuration code that usually goes in app.configure, like [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/):

```
app.configure(function() {
  // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
  // persistent login sessions (recommended).
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
});
```

Any ideas? server and router don't accept use().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union appears to use the `before` collection for this:

```
var server = union.createServer({
  before: [
    connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }), // for `passport.session()`
    passport.initialize(),
    passport.session(),

    // etc.
  ]
});
```

From the ["API" documentation](https://github.com/flatiron/union#readme):

```
@option before {Array} 
    The `before` value is an array of middlewares, which are used to route and serve incoming 
    requests. For instance, in the example, `favicon` is a middleware which handles requests 
    for `/favicon.ico`.
```

Comment: 'before' is called with every request. app.configure only once when the app loads. So that's not the same (and produces a lot of overhead).

Comment: @Patrick That's how [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/)-based middleware work -- they have to be able to respond to each request, or they pass it onto the next middleware. [`app.configure`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) sets up the same scenario; it just opts for a series of `app.use` calls (with the option of attaching them to various deployment modes) rather than a single, constant `before` array. This is why it can help to be picky about the middleware you use -- each one will invariably add some overhead.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I am used to the scenario in Express. I just wonder, as Passport doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Union supports connect middlewares via the `before` property, as previously mentioned by others. However, union does not handle application configuration; flatiron does. The api, however, is significantly different from express.

For example, configuring an application may look something like this:

```
var path = require('path'),
    flatiron = require('flatiron'),
    app = flatiron.app,
    plugins = flatiron.plugins,
    connect = require('connect'), // most connect middlewares work with flatiron ootb
    passport = require('passport');

// Use flatiron's http plugin (not the same as a middleware!)
app.use(plugins.http);

// configuration consists of key/value pairs, not of function blocks associated with
// certain "environments".
// Here's *a* way you can handle environment-based configs; there are others!
app.config.file(path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  'config',
  (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'config') + '.json'
));

// Use our config to set the secret
app.http.before.push(connect.session({
  secret: app.config.get('secret') || 'keyboard cat' //default
}))
app.http.before.push(passport.initialize());
app.http.before.push(passport.session());
```

I haven't tried running this example (I'm sure there are more details here) but hopefully this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just built a wrapper to integrate Passport.js with Flatiron.js.

https://npmjs.org/package/flatiron-passport

https://github.com/travist/flatiron-passport

Please read the README.md on how to use it and apply it to your application.

I have tested it on LocalStrategy, but it should work for other strategies.

Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Comment: I am not promoting anything other than a free and open source package  that I wrote to solve this persons question regarding integrating passport.js with flatiron.js.  I also disclosed that I wrote it.  Do the self-promotion guidelines prohibit me from providing links to code, or should I copy and paste it directly to my answer.  Sorry... just new to contributing to stackoverflow, so not completely sure how I violated terms.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? That something is free or open source has no bearing whatever here. I'm not saying you violated anything. I'm making a strong suggestion you read and understand.